# Proof of Theorem 1.2.11; Statistical Inference

Tags: probability, statistics, proof-verification, proof-writing

Looking for a quick check on this "proof", since I think the book's one is too hand wavy (or I'm just not mature enough yet):

Theorem: If $P$ is a probability function, then
$$ P ( \cup_{i=1}^\infty A_i) \leq \sum_{i = 1}^\infty P(A_i) $$

Proof:
Not sure about how to do this one:
$$ \cup_{i=1}^\infty (A_i / \cup_{j=1}^{i-1} A_j) = \cup_{i=1}^\infty A_i $$
Lets assume that we have proved that.
Let $A_i^* = A_i / \cup_{j=1}^{i-1} A_j.$
Lets prove the statement of the theorem now:
Let $i$ and $k$ be any arbitrary integers such that $i > k$. The opposite case is symmetric. Prove $A_i^* \cap A_k^* = \emptyset$.

$$ A_i^* \cap A_k^* $$
$$ A_i \cap (\cap_{j=1}^{i-1} A_j^C) \cap A_k \cap (\cap_{l=1}^{k-1} A_l^C) $$
Using associative law, idempotent law and the assumption that $i > k$, 
$$ A_i \cap A_k \cap (\cap_{j=1}^k A_j^C). $$
Assume that 
$$ A_i \cap A_k \cap (\cap_{j=1}^k A_j^C) \neq \emptyset.$$
Let $x \in A_i \cap A_k \cap (\cap_{j=1}^{k-1} A_j^C)$. Then $x \in A_i, x \in A_k, x \in A_1, x \in A_2, ..., x \in A_{i-1}$.
But then $x \in A_k$ and $x \in A_k^C$, so $A_k = \emptyset$. But then $A_i \cap A_k \cap (\cap_{j=1}^k A_j) = \emptyset$, which is a contradiction.
So then the $A^{*}$'s are disjoint.
So $P(\cup_{i=1}^\infty A_i*) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty P(A_i)$. Since $A_i^* \subset A_i$ by construction, $P(A_i^*) \leq P(A_i)$ for any $i$. So the theorem is true.

Comment: As stated, your theorem is patently false. Do you intend for the $A_i$ to be disjoint?

Comment: Just edited; should be correct now I believe

Comment: Just because of the way $A^*_i$ are constructed, they are disjoint. We are starting with $A^*_1=A_1$. Then $A^*_2$ is $A_2$ with $A_1$ taken out, etc. so that any element accounted for by a previous $A^*_k$ is excluded from $A^*_i$ for $i > k$. With that construction, the union of $A_i$ is exactly the union of $A^*_i$. I am not seeing any hand-waving in that argument. Can you explain why you think there is a need for this elaborate proof?

Comment: Okay, so what I don't understand is how much is enough when it comes to "obvious" things. From what I understand, something is "obvious" if it follows plainly from the axioms. For example, "$A_2^*$ is $A_2$ with $A_1$ taken out". What does it mean to be "taken out"? Let's use the / symbol to denote that, where $A\cup B^C = A/B$. Then how do we know they are pairwise disjoint? We use the definition of pairwise disjoint and the laws of set theory to make it plainly clear. I understand it's intuitively obvious but I think that it's important to still make it clear with the axioms available.

Comment: $A^*_2 = A_2 \cap A^C_1$ which by definitions of $\cap$ and complements readily implies that $A^*_2 $ and $A^*_1 = A_1$ are disjoint. $A^*_1 \cap A^*_2 = A^*_1 \cap A_2 \cap A^{*C}_1 = \emptyset$.

Comment: Then $A^*_3$ is defined as $A_3$ taking away any elements already accounted for by $A^*_1$ and $A^*_2$. You can write the formal $\cap$ symbols if you like and convince yourself the $A^*_j$'s are indeed being constructed being disjoint. Further, it is clear that together they contain all elements carried by the original $A_j$'s.